# Function average() on Array doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin

I decided to write the first class in my project in Kotlin.

I see in doc that there is average function on array and iterable http://apimirror.com/kotlin/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-iterable/index

So I wrote code like that:

```
val numbers: IntArray = intArrayOf(11, 20, 30, 40, 50)
val average: Float = numbers.average()
```

It works in try.kotlinlang.org, but in Android Studio, I get:

> Unresolved reference: average

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably missing the dependency to the Kotlin standard library from your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    ...
}
```

If you haven't configured your project at all yet, you can also do it by going to `Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin in Project`.

You can also see the official docs for how to set up Kotlin with [Android](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-android.html) and [Gradle](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html) in general.

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs you linked, that function returns a `Double`, not a `Float`. I get complaints about that in IntelliJ.

Try this instead:

```
val numbers: IntArray = intArrayOf(11, 20, 30, 40, 50)
val average: Double = numbers.average()
```

Or leave off the types entirely:

```
val numbers = intArrayOf(11, 20, 30, 40, 50)
val average = numbers.average()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the return type of average()  function [here](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/average.html), it returns Double not Float So use Double instead. We use Double instead of Float in Kotlin Mostly.